# Junit test in IntelliJ IDE can't see class for testing

Tags: java, junit, intellij-idea

I created simple Java project in IntelliJ, one class (RandomizedQueue) and generated JUnit test class for it. So it's just two files and they both are in the same directory - src.

Everything compiled and all was well. For some time. Then *suddenly* - it stopped with this error:

```
java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   class RandomizedQueue
  location: class RandomizedQueueTest
```

I tried everything I could think of. Recreating a project worked for a while but the same error reappeared (without any obvious reason). I can't find any logic in this! Compilation from cmd does work.

I tried deleting everything from class and test - and I still can't make an instance in test method.

[here is the whole project](http://www.sendspace.com/file/tflge2)

Comment: Please provide your failing source code.

Comment: @Smutje added link to the question

Comment: Are you sure that IntelliJ has identified your source and test folders appropriately?

Comment: @Makoto I'm not sure about anything right now. It kinda worked for a couple of days. Right now, just by creating a new file and copying code I managed to compile it. I don't understand what's going on

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See those white x-es next to the class name?

[image]

Somehow you have excluded RandomizedQueue class from the compilation.

[image]

Remove it from the excludes and everything will be back to where it was before.

PS: Coursera FTW :-)

Comment: Oh my god, you are right! I must have pressed some hotkey. It was driving me crazy, thank you so much!

Comment: @Amomum It is a great functionality when working with new projects, if you need to hit the ground running, and not everything compiles because of the dependencies, you can exclude some classes. Two caveats though: it is better to keep an eye on the list and don't go too deep into the project with the exclusions. :-)

Comment: @kukido I didn't even notice that little x-es on filenames :) Excluding from build is of course useful sometimes.. if you do it on purpose, not by accident.

Comment: I am in a kotlin project, did not see those white x's but checked anyway. This was still my problem!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. I fixed it by rebuilding the package in which the tests were located. Right click on the package and select "rebuild 'package name'".

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue every once in a while in my gradle projects (I'm on IntelliJ 2018.2.4 now).

The solution is to open a terminal and execute `gradlew idea`.